# How can I find names which were overwritten in the same Python namespace?

Tags: python, introspection

Suppose I have some Python code where the same identifier is used more than once-- for example,

```
def a():
    pass
def b():
    pass
def a():
    pass
```

How can I introspect that code to find out about the redefinition of `a`? `inspect` seems to know only the second definition of `a`, which is fair enough as far as it goes, but not helpful to me here.

Comment: What's redefinition of `a`? Anyway, the first function has disappeared in memory. If you want to get its information, you can either rebuild the function according to the source code or analyze it through the string.

Comment: @MechanicPig that makes sense. Can you comment that as an answer, so I can accept it?